# Android Xamarin grey out menu item in c#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, mobile, xamarin.android

I am trying to grey out my menu item text when it is disabled but am having trouble getting it to work. My menu.xml file is;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <group
        android:checkableBehavior="single">
      
        <item
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:checked="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/icon_item1"
            android:title="item1"
            app:actionLayout="@layout/item1Counter"/>
       
        <item
            android:id="@+id/about_us"
            android:checked="false"
            android:title="About Us" />
    </group>
</menu>
```

I disable the menu item above by the following:

```
var menu1 = menuList.Menu.GetItem(0);
menu1.SetEnabled(false);
//Here is where I want to grey out the icon
```

Anyone know how I could do that. Also, item1Counter is the item action layout which also has text that will be greyed out. I want everything in item to be greyed out when after I disable it. Anyone know how I can do that?

Comment: Did you try to define a selector drawable for it?You could refer to [StateList](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList).

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Thats what I try using but for some reason it doesnt call my selector. can you provide a example?

Comment: Could you show your item1Counter layout ?